# ExtJS: store - proxy - writer: how to always add/set a value to records when sync?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

After two days of struggling, I've made my own `Ext.data.Store` class that works (see code below).

Note that, even though all the configuration of the proxy and its writer are taken in account, the configuration `writeAllFields: true` is ignored and only the changed values are sent (which is a big problem to me).

So, now, to circumvent that (huge) problem, I'd like to **always** add a pre-defined value to the records that are sent (it's always one value, something like `id_partner: 3`). I need this for security reasons.

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.StoreHandleErrors', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'data.storehandleerrors',

    constructor: function(config) {
        config.autoLoad= true;
        config.autoSync= true;
        config.proxy.type= 'ajax';
        config.proxy.reader= {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        };
        config.proxy.writer= {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data'
        };
        config.proxy.listeners= {

            exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
                /* Code to handle exception */
            }
        };
        this.callParent([config]);
        this.on(
            'write',
            function(store, operation) {
                /* Code to show how the write op. went */
            },
            this
        );
        this.on(
            'beforesync',
            function(objects_to_sync, opts) {
                /* Code to add a pre-defined value to be sent: "id_partner: 3" */
            },
            this
        );
    }
});
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: `writeAllFields` should work. Have you tried to troubleshoot why it doesn't?

Comment: Nope, no answers from the Sencha forum (how strange...) as well. But I'm pretty sure it's a bug. I've found an ugly workaround, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you tried to debug Writer class to see what exactly is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code that works. It's a hack but it works with both ExtJS 4.0.7 and ExtJS 4.1 beta.

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.StoreHandleErrors', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'data.storehandleerrors',

    constructor: function(config) {
        /* (!!) proxy properties overwrite */
        config.autoLoad= true;
        config.autoSync= true;
        config.proxy.type= 'ajax';
        config.proxy.reader= {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        };
        config.proxy.writer= {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data'
        };
        config.proxy.listeners= {

            exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
                /* generic exception handling here */
            }
        };
        this.callParent([config]);
        this.on(
            'add',
            function(store, records, index, eOpts) {
                /* 27/04/2012 (!!) Hack: force property on all records */
                for (var i = 0; i <records.length; i++) {
                    records[i].data.id_partenaire=this.idPartenaire;
                };
            },
            this
        );
        this.on(
            'beforesync',
            /* 27/04/2012 (!!) Hack: force property on all records to false
             * and then ExtJs sees it's not the same so update
             * the value accordingly
             */
            function(sync, opts) {
                if (typeof sync.create!='undefined') {
                    for (var i = 0; i <sync.create.length; i++) {
                        sync.create[i].modified.id_partenaire=false;
                    };
                }
                if (typeof sync.update!='undefined') {
                    for (var i = 0; i <sync.update.length; i++) {
                        sync.update[i].modified.id_partenaire=false;
                    };
                }
            },
            this
        );
        /* (!!) remember the property (it's not copied
         * when calling this.callParent([config]); )
         */
        this.idPartenaire=config.idPartenaire;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found in ExtJs "5.1" that the field will not be sent to the server, even though you've set "writeAllFields" to true, when the field type is not specified in the model..
for instance with this code:

```
"fields:[
        {name:'commission_id', type:'int'},
        {name:'name'},
        {name:'surname', type:'auto'},
    ]"
```

commission_id will be sent even though not changed. Name and Surname Won't be sent if not changed.